# FASM - Simple: lstrcpy & lstrcat - Resulting strings are incorrect

Tags: string, assembly, copy, appendto, fasm

I am trying to do a simple task in FASM that I have literally been struggling with for about two hours now.

I have commented the code with the goal and the issue, but I will explain.

I am trying to store the path to a specific file into a variable. The file is located in the Temp Directory. So I must first get the temp path, then append the file name to the end of the temp path.

I am trying to do this two times sequentially. But for some reason, my resulting strings end up "screwy".

My current code is as follows:

```
include "win32ax.inc"

entry start

section ".data" data readable writeable

TmpDir          rb 256d
aSTR            dd ?
bSTR            dd ?
cSTR            db "aFILE.txt",0
dSTR            db "bFILE.txt",0

section ".code" code readable executable

start:

        ;The goal is to get two seperate strings like so:
        ;1 - C:\PATH-TO-TEMP-DIR\aFILE.txt in "aSTR"
        ;2 - C:\PATH-TO-TEMP-DIR\bFILE.txt in "bSTR"

        ;Get temp directory
        invoke  GetTempPath,TmpDir,TmpDir

        ;Copy tempdir into aSTR
        invoke  lstrcpy,aSTR,TmpDir
        ;Add "aFILE.txt" to the end of aSTR
        invoke  lstrcat,aSTR,cSTR

        ;Copy tempdir into bSTR
        invoke  lstrcpy,bSTR,TmpDir
        ;Add "bFILE.txt" to the end of bSTR
        invoke  lstrcat,bSTR,dSTR

        ;Results in "C:\UC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\AppData\Local\Temp\A\\
        ;Instead of "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\aFILE.txt"
        invoke  MessageBox,0,aSTR,"Test",0
        ;Results in "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\AppData\Local\Temp\A\\"
        ;Instead of "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\bFILE.txt"
        invoke  MessageBox,0,bSTR,"Test",0

        invoke  ExitProcess,0

section ".idata" import readable writeable

        library kernel32,               "KERNEL32.DLL",\
                user32,                 "USER32.DLL"

        import  kernel32,\
                lstrcpy,                "lstrcpy",\
                lstrcat,                "lstrcat",\
                GetTempPath,            "GetTempPathA",\
                ExitProcess,            "ExitProcess"

        import  user32,\
                MessageBox,             "MessageBoxA"
```

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a _simple_ task in asm :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. one of your strings is:

```
C:\UC:\Users\u...
^^^^
```

almost as if there's only four bytes for storing it before the next item in memory.

I wonder if that could be anything to do with the fact that you're using `dd` to define the space for it. Nudge, nudge, wink, wink.

---

Enough humour, time for a more serious response. Why do you think that:

```
aSTR            dd ?
```

will give you enough space to store a path name? Surely it should be something more like:

```
aSTR            rb 512d
```

which should give you *heaps* of space (and similarly for `bSTR`).

---

In fact, you're first `cpy/cat` operation also overwrites `cSTR` and `dSTR`, making it even harder to figure out what happens with the second operation.

Try reserving enough space (as per above) then giving it another shot.

Comment: You my friend, are awesome. lol. Simply reserved the space and it is working like a charm. :facepalm: Thanks!

Comment: Not _just_ awesome, but modest as well :-)